# When to create references, store values and set references to null

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a couple of questions:

1. Regarding the creation of References to Objects and primitive
   values, I was wondering: when is it usually appropriate to store
   values in a variable?

   From my general knowledge, the rule of thumb would be to create
   references when the same value is **used more than once or to avoid
   hard-coding** E.g.

   ```
   String name = "Bob"; 
   System.out.println("Welcome " + name + ". Is your name really " + name + "?");
   ```

   Whereas if it is only used once like in the example below, it would
   be more performant to simply do the following.

   ```
   System.out.println("Welcome Bob");
   ```

   as opposed to

   ```
   String name = "Bob"; 
   System.out.println("Welcome " + name + ".");
   ```

   **Added question**: If we are talking about a variable that is used when   iterating over an array or enumerable object, which of the following would be more performant (assuming we are looping over an object like 1 million times)? Or would there be no difference and is simply a stylistic choice?

   For example,

   ```
   // nameArray is an extremely long array
   public static void loop(String[] nameArray) { 
       String name; //Should this be declared inside the loop? 
        int len = nameArray.length(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
            name = nameArray[i]; 
            System.out.println(name); 
        } 
   }
   ```

   or would this be more preferred?

   ```
    // nameArray is an extremely long array
   public static void loop(String[] nameArray) { 
        int len = nameArray.length(); 
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
            String name = nameArray[i]; //Declare String reference inside for loop
            System.out.println(name); 
        } 
   }
   ```
2. In regards to garbage collection, after a reference to an object/primitive
   has passed its useful life, is it **always good practice** to set
   that value to null to make it eligible for garbage collection (assuming that     there are no other references to that object/primitive value) ?

   For example,

   ```
   String name = "Bob"; 
   System.out.println("Welcome " + name + ".);
   name = null;
   ```

thank you in advance for taking time to look at this.

Comment: You really shouldn't care about garbage collection when you're writing code.

Comment: if `name` would be a local variable, setting it to null wouldn´t make much of a difference, since it´s lifecicle is over even though.

Comment: Thank you @Manu and Kevin for the insight. Everything makes more sense now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No it makes no difference - the object is allocated whether you use a local variable to refer to it or not. Use whatever is more readable.
2. It is almost ***never*** good practice to set values to null explicitly. There are a few corner cases, such as when not doing it would hold unnecessary references to variables that would otherwise be eligible for garbage collection (see for example: [*Effective Java* - Item 6: Eliminate obsolete object references](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=6)). In all other situations, limiting the scope of variables as much as possible is the most efficient way to help the garbage collector.

The bottom line being: use variables when you need them and let the garbage collector do its job, unless you have a compelling reason not to.

Comment: Also, keep variables in appropriately limited scope.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. I have added an extra question (highlighted in bold). If you have time/ are available, would appreciate it if you took time to take a look at it :).

Comment: @J.Lee Your two examples probably compile to the same bytecode, and even if they don't there won't be any performance difference.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the insight @assylias

Answer (score 1):

> From my general knowledge, the rule of thumb would be to create references when the same value is used more than once or to avoid hard-coding

Please, forget this rule. Use variables and their scope to help others (and you) understand your program more easily. You can do something like this

```
private static final String MY_UNCLE_NAME = "Bob"; 

System.out.println(String.format("Welcome %s.", MY_UNCLE_NAME));
```

**Updated**

> If we are talking about a variable that is used when iterating over an array or enumerable object, which of the following would be more performant (assuming we are looping over an object like 1 million times)? Or would there be no difference and is simply a stylistic choice?

Always use this (keep a scope of variables as less as possible and forget about local optimizations).

```
// nameArray is an extremely long array
public static void loop(String[] nameArray) { 
     int len = nameArray.length(); 
     for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
         String name = nameArray[i]; //Declare String reference inside for loop
         System.out.println(name); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Point taken. I will put more emphasis on readability and cohesion in the future :)

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you for the response!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. when is it usually appropriate to store values in a variable?

In most cases the answer is: When the code benefits from it from a maintenance perspective. If the code becomes easier to understand or debug, then use a variable.

> 2. After a reference to an object/primitive has passed its useful life, is it always good practice to set that value to null to make it eligible for garbage collection?

If the variable goes out of scope shortly after, then setting it to `null` will just unnecessarily clutter the code. I would use it only for long-lived variables, and perhaps for variables that point to large objects.